# Can Windows services be deployed from Visual Studio as easily as web projects?

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2017, webdeploy

I'm running an ASP.NET Core web service that's dead easy to deploy to IIS on a Windows Server using WebDeploy: Right-click the project in VS, choose Publish, done. The currently running site is backuped and then updated. Couldn't be easier.

However, Windows services are another matter. I'm taking over maintenance of a service that is currently updated by building the Release config, remote desktoping to the server, stopping the current service, renaming the folder the service executable resides in (for easy rollback in case something goes wrong), copying over the build output from the dev machine, renaming the copied folder to the service folder name so the service finds the executable, and starting the service.

**Is there a way to publish/update Windows services that is as easy as running WebDeploy?** I haven't found any. There's always the possibility of abusing WebDeploy and just replacing the Windows service head project with an ASP.NET head project running on IIS, but the service has nothing to do with the web and I have no idea whether there would be any side effects to this solution.

(I could of course just write a script that performs the copying etc., but a built-in VS deployment process as with web projects would be optimal. As for continuous integration/deployment, it is unfortunately not something we have ever done at my company.)